# provide access of a URL created in a server (using shinyR app) to everyone accessing in local desktop

Tags: r, url, shiny, port, shiny-server

I have created a model in R and created the interface using shiny R to open it in a browser. Now, all these are created in a server.

My question is:

How can i share this browser URL that gets open when i run the `shinyapp` with other people.

I mean, if i copy the `url` and opens it in a browser in my server, i am able to open it.

But if I try to open the same `url` from my local desktop, i am not able to open it.

It doesn't recognize the `url`.
my `url` is like `http://10.***.***.***:****` (* are all numbers, before colon(:), it is the IP address of the server and after colon(:) it is the port)

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is not clear whether you have installed `shiny-server` or not. Apologies if I'm saying things that you are already familiar with.

`shiny` is a R package that when you launch the application uses a "local" server to see locally the result of your work. But the resulting URL cannot be shared: it is local to you and your app.

You need to:

1. Download from RStudio the latest version of `shiny-server` and install it  on a server (works only on Linux-type machines). Please note this has nothing to do with installing R packages.
2. Install your project folder, e.g. `myApp`, onto a specific directory of the `shiny-server`, usually `/srv/shiny-server/myApp` & `chown - R` the folder to `shiny:shiny`
3. Make sure R is installed on the server box.
4. Install any R package required by the app
5. Go at `<your box IP address>:3838/myApp` to see your app working

Please consult the [latest admin guide for `shiny-server`](http://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/) for many more necessary details.